Pyqt5 GUI change color
My program works fine,
That is untill I am running my main thread function few times, and after few times the gui start turnning all white and grey, but functionallity works fine, have no idea why.
Thought it is worth mentioning that this bug could happen after just couple clicks on a button (which running all the code i provided below) and sometimes it happens after a 50/100 clicks, but it happens eventually.


tried to follow the code and change a few things but nothing seems to work, the problem is still reproduced.
The code i provided below is common to all functions in the code, so basically there is a main function that calls a chosen function and runs the chosen function within a Qthread.
there is alot of the code that going on so let me just show a specific function case.
Steps of execution from the second a click has being emitted,

The connection:
connecting the click signal of the button to function "start_stop_sb_thread" and passing as an argument the button object.

self.obj.Config_Etc_mechanical.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Functions.start_stop_sb_thread(self.obj.Config_Etc_mechanical))


start_stop_sb_thread function:
The function passes as an argument the function run_automation who basically responible to call the wanted function (see step 5)

def start_stop_sb_thread(self, button_ui_obj, usb_needed=False, kill_master=False):
self.gm.start_stop_test_thread(lambda: self.run_automation(button_ui_obj, usb_needed), bt_to_change="stop_automation", start_txt="Stop Automation",
                                       stop_txt="Run Automated Tests", kill_master=kill_master)


"start_stop_test_thread" gm class
this is my main theard controller which helps me to start and stop the thread,
the self.emit_ui_label function basically changing a ui obj text with signals (I know changing a text withing a Qthread should be with a pyqtSignal)

    def start_stop_test_thread(self, function, bt_to_change=None, start_txt=None, stop_txt=None, function_name=None,
                               kill_master=True):
        """
        This method enable you to start and stop a thread.

        kill_master = if False the button who called the function won't be able to kill the thread.
        this is in order to make a master button to kill thread.
        """
        if bt_to_change:
            self.test_worker.ext_finished_signal.connect(lambda: self.emit_ui_label(bt_to_change, stop_txt))

        self.test_worker.toggled_thread = True

        if not self.test_worker.running:
            if function_name is None:
                self.test_worker.start_thread(func=function)
            else:
                self.test_worker.start_thread(func=function, func_name=function_name)
            if bt_to_change:
                self.emit_ui_label(bt_to_change, start_txt)
        else:
            if kill_master:
                self.test_worker.ext_finished_signal.emit()
                self.test_worker.kill_thread()
                if self.iperf:
                    subprocess.Popen('Taskkill /IM iperf3.exe /F', shell=True)
                    self.iperf = False


start_thread function is a function of a worker that basically running the function within a Qthread:

class threader(QThread):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        super().__init__()
        self.fn = fn
    # #
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.fn()


# Create a worker class #
class Worker(QObject):
    my_started = pyqtSignal()
    my_finished = pyqtSignal()
    my_error = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    my_success = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self, func):
        try:
            self.my_started.emit()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            x = func()
            if x is None or True or 1:
                self.my_success.emit()
                self.my_finished.emit()
                return

            elif type(x) is list:
                if x[0] == -1:
                    function_error = x[1]
                    trace_back = x[2]
                    print(f'\nFunction error: {function_error}')
                    print(trace_back)
                    self.my_error.emit(str(function_error), trace_back,
                                       str(func.__name__))
                    self.my_finished.emit()
                    return

        except Exception as e:
            self.trace_back = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(f'\nFunction error: {e}')
            print(self.trace_back)
            self.my_error.emit(str(e), self.trace_back)

        self.my_finished.emit()


# Creating thread manger class #
class CreateThread(Worker, QObject):
    ext_finished_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, atp_name):
        super(CreateThread, self).__init__()
        self.stop_flag = False
        self.atp_name = atp_name
        self.toggled_thread = False
        self.running = False

    def start_thread(self, func, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        if type(func) != functools.partial:
            self.func_name = func.__name__
        else:
            self.func_name = self.kwargs['func_name']


        if self.stop_flag:
            return

        # Checking if func name is given and if not it will be simply function
        if self.func_name == '<lambda>':
            if bool(self.kwargs) and 'func_name' in self.kwargs:
                self.func_name = self.kwargs['func_name']
            else:
                self.func_name = 'function'

        # Thread and Worker init #
        self.worker = Worker()
        act = partial(self.worker.run, func)
        self.thread = threader(act)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        # Signal to Function connection #
        self.worker.my_started.connect(self.started_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.finished_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_error.connect(self.error_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_success.connect(self.success_signal_connection)

        # Handling the worker and the thread deletion #
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.ext_finished_signal.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        self.running = True
        self.thread.start()

    def kill_thread(self):
        """Terminating the thread"""
        if self.running:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.running = False
        print('\nFunction stopped ! ')

    # Connect signals from worker #
    @pyqtSlot()
    def started_signal_connection(self):
        if not self.toggled_thread:
            self.stop_flag = True
        print(f"\nFunction {self.func_name} started\n")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished_signal_connection(self):
        self.stop_flag = False
        self.running = False
        self.ext_finished_signal.emit()
        print("\nFinished")

    @pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def error_signal_connection(self, error_name, trace_back):
        # THIS CODE GENERATING A TXT FILE WITH THE TRACEBACK.
        # DELTED BECAUSE IT IS NOT INTERESTING.        

    @pyqtSlot()
    def success_signal_connection(self):
        print("\nSuccess")


run_automation:
this function eventually calls the function which i want to run within the thread.

    def run_automation(self, button_ui_obj, usb_needed=False):
        """This function runs the automation tests"""

        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        print_colored(f'\n----- {button_ui_obj.text()} -----', OKCYAN)

        self.update_com_ports()

        if not self.com_connected and usb_needed:
            return

        self.func_is_running_flag = True

        self.cbs_to_funcs[button_ui_obj]()
        if button_ui_obj.objectName() in ['cb_xacu_uboot', 'cb_tx_rx_uboot', 'cb_rfic', 'cb_panels_sn']:
            sleep(1)

        stop_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_difference = round((stop_time - start_time).total_seconds() / 60, 2)
        print("\nStart time:", start_time.strftime("***** %H:%M:%S *****"))
        print("Stop time:", stop_time.strftime("***** %H:%M:%S *****"))
        print("Minutes passed:", time_difference)

        self.func_is_running_flag = False


Btw managed to narrow the scope of the problem to the method "start_stop_test_thread", something is not right there please help me out

someone have any insight ?

@CarlHR Thank you very much for replaying. You are absoultly right, this code is a little bit complicate because it is built on many classes, let me try to explain in the main thread what happens every step from the second a click is being emitted. as for "once the window turns white and grey" i can still interact with the screen widget and the gui is fully functional.

How do you set the CSS of your application? Do you make use of a thread for it (such as CreateThread.start_thread)?

@CarlHR
The way im setting the CSS is with QTdesigner and just uploading the ui file with a simple short script with classes. Also worth mentioning that i have a func that connects all Qcombox to pass fail setStylesheet, thought i isolated that it is not the problem.

I have tested your class CreateThread, and the app crashes if I execute start_thread 2x or more, because as it can be seen on the code, you're discarding previous references of self.worker and self.thread, which will be garbage collected by python. Also, CreateThread should behave closely, if not the same, as a QThreadPool. Is there any reason to not use it? Try to use it in your code instead of the CreateThread class, as some memory leaks might be happening behind the screen, and it might be affecting the CSS style of your application. If it doesn't work, I have no more clues. Good luck!

@CarlHR Hey, thank you very much for replaying. There is a reason im not using QThreadPool because if i understanded correctly the Qpool queing the threads, but i want to allow the user to run only one thread at a time without Queing the next threads in a pool. btw there is no reason that it should crash on the second call to the function in your code, perhaps you wrote it wrong, may i see ?

What I did was: 1. Define a dummy function foo(). It doesn't need to do anything, maybe a print to see it being executed; 2. Create an instance of CreateThread as ct; 3. Call ct.start_thread(foo) 2x. The app should crash at the 2nd call. The reason is simple, whenever you're creating a new QThread, you're not doing anything with the previous one. You're expecting them to be finished right before the 2nd call. My example shows that things may not happen as expected.

The same would happen if you click a button that start/stops a thread, 50x times or so. Depending on how fast the button is clicked, it could be faster than the function can process its script, so there may be a time a crash is expected. Look... if you don't know much about memory and garbage collection, (pointers maybe?) any variable/instance defined on your code, that you don't set a strong reference to it and properly release it, may be causing problems somewhere else. The example I've shown may be just the peak of the iceberg, which is why its so difficult to track the problem.

@CarlHR "The reason is simple, whenever you're creating a new QThread, you're not doing anything with the previous one."
You would be correct but I did take this in notice, it is hard to see but the user is unable to call a second Qthread untill the first one is finished because the worker has "self.stop_flag" preventing the user from running another thread:
"   if self.stop_flag:
return"
I wont say im expert at memory management and garbage collection, though i do take it in mind when im coding.

@CarlHR Perhaps what happens in the backround is that the "stop_flag" somehow fails to prevent the second function from being called and then the app get all messed up.
is that possible ?

@CarlHR Quick update, you are right because i debugged this problem by trying to eliminate each factor i might suspect related to the problem, it all comes down to the logic of the CreateThread, although it is not crashing the program as you said, because im using it only with Pyqt apps, as i showed in this main thread. So basically for some reason after a several uses of the CreateThread class, something is overlapping like you said, though im having a hard time figure out what it is

Here are some tips to help you debug. Can't you rewrite CreateThread as a QThreadPool subclass, only to see if that's the actual problem? Even if it doesn't behave the same way as the original class (instead of killing a thread, just ignore it), at least you can move one step closer to pinpoint the problem. Also, you could check if the problem doesn't happen after you call QThread.terminate (ensuring there'a a QThread.wait afterwards, there's no wait on the code provided), the docs warnings about it shouldn't be easily discarded.
